# Question title not appearing for this question in Google search

Tags: bug

I was doing a Google search and stumbled [across this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078083/lets-encrypt-ssl-couldnt-start-by-error-eacces-permission-denied-open-et), and it just says "Ask Question" in the Google search results instead of the question's title.

My exact search was:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied open /etc/letsencrypt/live/bytesgenesis.com/privkey.pem

Here are some screenshots:
[image: When the question is opened]
[image: When it appears inside a Google search]

Comment: Seems like you're reporting a bug for Google on Stack Overflow's website...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think it's a Google bug because 1, it works with all other questions, and 2, Google, by default, takes the webpage's title at that place instead of any other info, so it seems that there is a problem with how StackOverflow is rendering those. Of course, this is just assumptions, I am not entirely sure of this but this is not normal in Google searches, and does not happen with other questions.